# PHP CURL getting 400 error in loop

Tags: php, regex, curl, urlencode, url-encoding

here the foreach loops returns a phone number which goes in the link but whenever I try to run this script it gives me the error 400 bad request. I have also tried using the useragent but even that does not solve the error. any help would be great.

PS. this is my first question please let me know if I can provide anything to solve this problem.

```
foreach($var5 as $number) {
     $ch = curl_init();
     $ch1="http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=0000000000&pass=xxxxxxxx&senderid=xxxxxxx&to=$number&msg=hey";
     echo $ch1;
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$ch1");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36');
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
}
```

**Update:**

When I add `urlencode` the bad request definitely goes but I want this url to execute: `http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=1234567890&pass=password&senderid=ID&to=+ 9408644603&msg=hey` but instead this url is executed: `http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=1234567890&pass=password&senderid=ID&to=%2B+9408644603&msg=hey`

Also here I have only applied `urlencode` to the phone number rest of the fields I'm entering myself directly. Also the bad request probably goes as the api won't execute if the phone number is not correct.

Comment: do you get a `400` response in all requests of the loop?

Comment: @nikos.svnk yes I get a error saying bad request 400 multiple times.

Comment: I'm new to this so could you tell me how to determine the same? @chris85

Comment: @chris85 No I don't the pass the values like: <?php
$var="xyz";
$var1="abc";
$ch1="http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=$var1&pass=$xyz&senderid=xxxxxxx&to=$number&msg=hey";
?>

Comment: Try encoding them `$var=urlencode("xyz");` or encode them at the URL passing if you use those vars elsewhere.

Comment: @chris85 when I add urlencode the bad request definitely goes but I want this url to execute http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=1234567890&pass=password&senderid=ID&to=+ 9408644603&msg=hey  but instead this url is executed http://bmsms.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=1234567890&pass=password&senderid=ID&to=%2B+9408644603&msg=hey also here I have only applied urlencode to the phone number rest of the fields I'm entering my self directly. Also the bad request probably goes as the api won't execute if the phone number is not correct.

Comment: @chris85 yes there is a space between "+" and "940844603" it's how I receive the value from the server but it's okay though and works fine without urlencode

Comment: @chris85 to=9408644603 works but I don't know how to change each value that comes from the server from "+ 9408644603" to "9408644603" and also to=%B9408644603 gives an error that the phone number has to be 10 digits

Comment: @chris85 but still %2B9408644603 does not work it gives the error of the phone number has to be 10 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` in the phone numbers for some reason is breaking the receiving applications system. URL encoding doesn't resolve this because they only want numbers. You can use a regex to replace all the leading, non-numerical, characters with nothing.

```
preg_replace('/^\D+/','', $serverthing)
```

`\D` is a non number (`\d` is a number).
`^` is the start of the string.
`+` is one or more of the previous character/group.
`/`s are delimiters showing the start and end of the regex.